# Sort rows differently when "no data" is present

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I'm using the `DataTables` plugin in a fairly standard way. This is the `ready` event content:

```
jQuery('#languages_table').DataTable({
    pageLength: 100,
    columns: [
      { orderDataType: "dom-text" },
      { orderDataType: "dom-text" },
      { orderDataType: "dom-text" },
      { orderDataType: "dom-text", type: "num" },
      { orderable: false },
      { orderable: false }
    ]
  });
```

However, in some cases the cells have no information, so I need to show something like *no data*.

This obviously messes with the sorting system (especially for the numeric columns), ordering them in unwanted places.

I already managed to get rid of this issue for the numbers by making the cell completely empty (so no writing *no data* at all), and adding that text by css:

```
#languages_table td:empty::before {
  content: "no data";
}
```

This way the cell counts as zero, and descending searches, they appear at the very bottom (as it's much more useful to sort the numbers in this way).

It's awful (and a pain for translations), but it does the trick.

I now need the same for textual cells, but in this case, the sorting should place the empty cells at the bottom of an ascending search (which is in this case more interesting), and I certainly don't know how to do that.

Is there a way to manually deal with these edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom sorting function.  You can scope this to a custom type you define.

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "null-last-pre": function ( a ) {
        // Preprocess data if you need to.  Currently doing nothing
        return a;
    },

    "null-last-asc": function( a, b ) {
        return (a===null)-(b===null) || +(a>b)||-(a<b);
    },

    "null-last-desc": function(a,b) {
        return (a===null)-(b===null) || -(a>b)||+(a<b);
    }
});
```

Then in add columnDefs to your options like this:

```
columnDefs: [
   { type: 'null-last', targets: [0,1,2,3,4,5] }
 ]
```

Also remove the "type: 'num'" from your column definition and as long as the data is "null" or "undefined" then it should properly sort things.  If you need the type conversion of the 'num' type then just remove '3' from the targets array.  Not sure which type takes precedence (columnDef or column).